# In MySQL query, VARCHAR(100) gets output as "[partnumber]" although in a query with more columns, it is still shown as 'p-12345'

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, format

**This is a bad question since I only made a mistake in selecting by chance a client that had garbage data and must have changed the where condition during tests, and it was also a problem of a join that I did not even mention in the question that led to so many of the strange `[partnumber]` entries that the limit 10 query showed *only* those. So that I thought the whole column would have this value. I am not sure whether I should delete it. It might also help someone else who has garbage data without knowing about it. You may vote to close the question if you think it has wasted your time. For I see myself that this can be a waste of time reading.**

In a normal `SELECT p.* FROM table` query with many columns, the output shows values in a needed column, every number shows up, showing the column with the partnumber (a partially numeric number like p-12345) only:

[image]

But when I ask for only that column alone with `SELECT client_x FROM table`, I get:

[image]

### UPDATE:

I can see the values of that column now!! They are not showing `[partnumber]` anymore in each row, but instead, there are numbers and strings and empty values as well in it.

[image]

I had the where condition on the client in it, and the value in that client is always [partnumber]. It is garbage only in that client.

### UPDATE end

The column data type is `varchar(100)`. It should be treated as a normal string.

[image]

I use DBeaver, but that should not play a role.

If I concatenate the column with some string, the value appears as an empty string:

`SELECT CONCAT("test", client_x) FROM table`

returns just "test" as values.

How can I avoid this `[partnumber]` output in the column output and show the part number string instead, like it is shown when I just run `SELECT * FROM table`?

Comment: Please provide the full query of what you're using in both cases. Feel free to change the names of things but don't completely obfuscate the query.

Comment: As @J.D. said, provide the full query. My guess, from what you'v shown, is that you're actually selecting [partnumber] as a text string instead of as a column name, and then giving it an alias of client_xxx.

Comment: @J.D. The full query does not add anything. It is not about the query. The difference is that abstract: `SELECT * FROM table` gives you results, `SELECT MY_COLUMN FROM table` only shows `[part_number]`. This has nothing to do with the query since it is just a SELECT of a table. I just want to see the same values of that strange column as those which are shown when running `SELECT * FROM table`

Comment: As you see from Rick James's answer, the query was relevant, as you even admit in the comments. Please keep this in mind for future questions, that you should always provide the query, despite how irrelevant you may think it is (even if not directly related, it adds context at least). It's one of the minimum pieces of information for asking a question on here, generally.

Comment: @J.D. yes, you are right, the query made it. I also accepted it now and I am sorry for having said so. I had thought that the partnumber is a system-made output. When asking for it, I got it, while the query that selected all did not have the where condition and showed values. It was that easy, and I did not think that I would make such a mistake just because that entry seemed so systemic. Problem with sharing queries is that I have to change so much to keep a minimum privacy, which takes time and nerves. My bad.

Comment: No problem at all. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to manipulate the data, you cannot use `SELECT *`.

If you are seeing `[partnumber]` coming from the table, then GIGO.

Note:  MySQL does not use brackets.  If the column is named `partnumber then either of these will work, but brackets won't:

```
partnumber
`partnumber`
```

Some other db engines use brackets.

If the table contains `1234567`, but you want to see `p-1234567`:

```
SELECT  CONCAT('p-', partnumber) AS partnumber, ...
```

If the table contains `p-1234567` and you want to display `1234567`, here is a way *assuming* the first 2 characters need to be stripped:

```
SELECT  MID(partnumber, 3) AS partnumber, ...
```

If neither of those answer your question, please rephrase it.

Comment: I do not want to manipulate, I just want to see the values of that column, not a strange placeholder like `[partnumber]`. `GIGO` = `Garbage in, garbage out` is not helpful here since there is no garbage in that column, as the `SELECT * FROM table` command shows the right values. I also do not want to change the output of that column by dropping `p-` or adding it or whatever, I just want to see the values "as they are".

Comment: I found it out I think. You are right, the `[partnumber]` is really just garbage in the column, I found it as plain string in there since I could somehow query that column now. I guess that I had a wrong join on it which led to duplicating of the first filled entry (though this is still very strange, why did it not take the empty strings at first then?). The first two lines' values are empty, the third line has `[partnumber]`. For some reason, I got an output that repeated the `[partnumber]`, as in the screenshots above. As the entry is just garbage, I can accept your answer. Bad question.

Comment: Found it out again. I had the where condition on the client in it, and the value in that client is always `[partnumber]`. It is garbage only in that client.